# How To Scale Object Along Any Axis (In 3D Space)

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, scale

I'm trying to write a physics simulator in c++ with opengl and I need to be able to scale objects (mostly cubes right now) along the axis that the camera is facing.

I can draw objects perfectly fine using this as my Model Matrix:

```
mat4 Model = Translate(cube.Position - float3(gl.Position.x, gl.Position.y, -gl.Position.z)) * Rotate(cube.Rotation) * Scale(cube.Scale);
```

Where gl.Position is the cam's position, float3 is a vec3 like class I wrote, etc...

So i tried to modify that line to include a scaling factor before all else (where stuff at the end is applied first):

```
mat4 Model = Translate(cube.Position - float3(gl.Position.x, gl.Position.y, -gl.Position.z)) * Rotate(cube.Rotation) * Scale(cube.Scale) * (Rotate(float3(gl.Rotation.x, gl.Rotation.y, gl.Rotation.z)) * Scale(float3(1.0f, 1.0f, sqrt(1 - (velocity * velocity)))) * Rotate(float3(tau - gl.Rotation.x, tau - gl.Rotation.y, tau - gl.Rotation.z)));
```

It's the last part that is important, where I rotate the object, scale it, then rotate it back.. the sqrt(1 - (velocity * velocity)) is the physics part (Lorentz contraction) and gl.Rotation is a vec3 where each axis holds the pitch, yaw, and roll in radians of the cam. My translate, rotate, etc. functions work properly, but I need help with the theory of creating a matrix to scale.

Comment: There's further discussion of this at https://www.gamedev.net/topic/541643-scaling-along-arbitrary-axis/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by writing this function that is based off of pippin1289's solution

```
mat4 ScaleOnAxis(float3 a)
{
    a = Norm3f(a);

    if(a == x || (a.x == -1.0f && a.y == 0.0f && a.z == 0.0f))
        return Scale(0.2f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    float3 axis = Cross(a, x);
    float theta = acos(Dot(a, x));

    if(theta > pi / 2)
    {
        axis = axis * -1.0f;
        theta = pi - theta;
    }

    Quaternion ToRotation(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z, theta);
    Quaternion FromRotation(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z, tau - theta);

    return mat4(FromRotation) * (Scale(float3(0.2f, 1.0f, 1.0f)) * mat4(ToRotation));
}
```

It returns a matrix that will scale by 0.2 on a axis

Answer (score 1):

Scaling matrices are of the form:

```
{{s_x, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, s_y, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, s_z, 0},
 {0,  0,  0, 1}}
```

Assuming uniform coordinates.

To apply them, you need to scale, then rotate, then translate. I recommend using gl functions to do this. Assume you want your object at position x, y, z, and its rotation is in a quaternion {theta, r_x, r_y, r_z}. Scaling and rotation need to occur in the model coordinate frame. GL applies the transformations in an appropriate order, so its code would look like this:

```
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
glRotatef(theta, r_x, r_y, r_z);
glScalef(s_x, s_y, s_z);

//draw my model
```

Comment: maybe you didn't understand my problem, see that the scale matrix would only scale on the x, y, and z axes independantly, (for example, turning a cube into a rectangular prism) but it wouldn't be able to scale along a vector of (0.5, 0, 0.5) creating a 3d parallelogram (which is what i need)

Comment: Why would glScale(0.5, 0, 0.5) not produce the effect you want? or providing 0.5 for whatever scaling magnitude you need.

Comment: because glScale would half it's length, zero it's height, and half it's width, (creating a small square), as opposed to scaling it once along the (0.5, 0, 0.5) vector (creating a shape that no longer has only 90 deg angles)

Comment: ok (0.5, 1, 0.5)? This would half the x and z components and keep the y the same. I guess I am not clear on why glScale will not work. Are you looking for shear? instead of scaling?

Comment: Thinking about it more, what you need to do is to rotate the model by a rotation which places the vector along the x axis, scale along the x-axis by whatever magnitude, then reverse the rotation. This would allow scaling along an arbitrary vector.

Comment: thank you for your continued help, that is exactly what I'm implementing now!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any resources online for solving this issue using the GLM library and have finally found an answer to my issue thanks to the comment thread by @pippin1289, and am writing this in hopes it can help someone in the future, despite the fact the thread is 10 years old.

If you wanted to, for example, scale an object 3x on an axis oriented 45 degrees between the x and z axis and passing through point (1, 0, 0) in a 3-dimensional space, you would write:

```
M = glm::mat4(1);
M = glm::translate(M, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
M = glm::rotate(M, glm::radians(45.0f), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
M = glm::scale(M, glm::vec3(3, 1, 1));
M = glm::rotate(M, glm::radians(-45.0f), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
M = glm::translate(M, glm::vec3(-1, 0, 0));
```

Essentially you want to first position your object in the point through which the arbitrary axis passes, perform the required rotation, then perform the scaling along only one of the dimensions, before reversing the scaling and translations performed beforehand.

As indicated by @pippin1289, *you rotate the model by a rotation which places the arbitrary vector along the x axis*.

Hope this is of use to anyone struggling with what is seemingly a simple issue!